# The netstart command

Tags: networking

I ran the command "netstat -anc | grep x.x.x.x.xxxx" on linux redhat and at specific times I get the below results

```
tcp     1492   1492 y.y.y.y:port        x.x.x.x:port             ESTABLISHED 
tcp     1492   1492 y.y.y.y:port        x.x.x.x:port             ESTABLISHED 
tcp     1145   9876 y.y.y.y:port        x.x.x.x:port             ESTABLISHED 
tcp     1855    784 y.y.y.y:port        x.x.x.x:port             ESTABLISHED
```

How can find out the process if any runs to cause this anormally.
I need help in analysing this scenario.

Note that the filling of those queues is happening at specific times eg 3pm

I expect the command to produce results below with a minimum spike

```
tcp        0      0 y.y.y.y:port        x.x.x.x:port             ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 y.y.y.y:port        x.x.x.x:port             ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 y.y.y.y:port        x.x.x.x:port             ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 y.y.y.y:port        x.x.x.x:port             ESTABLISHED'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
man netstat
       -p, --program
           Show the PID and name of the program to which each socket belongs.
```

Comment: I am failing to interpret the results of this command would you mind explaining what it does

Comment: PID is the Process ID. You can see which process maintains that connection. Usually I use the netstat -anp command.